# ETL Process in SSIS - Best Practices

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl

I'm trying to figure out what are the best practices to build a new ETL process in **SSIS**.

I have a table source in **sql server** and I want to make to it some transformations, add columns, Join, etc.

My question is, should I create a **View/SP** with all the transformations or to make the joins and transformation with **"Derived Column"** and **"Lookup"** in SSIS?

I'm asking it in the performance/maintenance aspects.

I think the performance should be the same, but the maintenance of it is my big concern.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: This is going to likely come to a prefence thing. I find that there isn't really a "best" way for ETL; it's what works for you and your business. For where I work at the moment, I find that an ELT process works best; use SSIS to extract and load the data in it's raw form; then use SQL Server to transform that data into the production requirements. It's totally up to you what way you go.

Comment: I see. So just to be sure, You create your ETL process in SSIS, but  the transformations of the data you do in the SQL Server. And the ETL in the SSIS calls to the SP you created?

Comment: That's one option yes, however, you can do the transformations in SSIS within the dataflow and then load. Like I said, there is no "best practice" per say.

Comment: I've had to maintain both 'styles' of SSIS ETL package. In my opinion keeping the transformations inside SPs is far far easier to maintain, and more flexiable, plus you can keep all the SQL in a Visual Studio database project, rather than embedded inside SSIS. I've also had some nightmare Lookup Transformations to deal with that eat memory and fail on production which could only be resolved by removing and redeveloping to use SQL joins in the datasource instead.

Comment: I would suggest in this case that you stay inside the database (with stored proc) since you already have the data "loaded" in a table. SSIS becomes more useful when you have external sources. I personally like ETL vs ELT (to me it's easier to hand off to someone else)

Answer (score 2):

My rule of thumb is that anything you can do in TSQL, you should do in TSQL instead of in SSIS.   It will perform faster.   Lookups in the dataflow are definitely slower than joins in TSQL.

Comment: I partly agree with you, if you consider merge script from a linked server vs using SSIS , i will prefer SSIS. Connecting to a linked server or importing data from another server, i prefer to use SSIS.

Comment: Yes, I did assume that all the TSQL operations were happening on the same server.   If they are not the same server, then use SSIS.